# Inline Клавиатура

Tags: python, telegram-bot, inline

Эксперементирую с inline клавой. Сделал inline клавиатуру с одной кнопкой. При нажатии просто меняется цифра на кнопе.  Но мне надо, чтобы бот по истечению заданного времени выдал некий результат. Например, удалил эту кнопку.  А он у меня обрабатывает время только после нажатия на inline кнопку. Я понимаю, что надо установить некий таймер, но не могу понять, куда его впихнуть в коде? Внизу код без таймера. Хелп, плиз

```
import telebot
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup() 
    markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Старт', callback_data=1))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Нажми", reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def query_handler(call):
    print(tnow)
    counter1 = int(call.data)
    if call.data == str(counter1):
        markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()  
        markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(counter1), callback_data=counter1+1))
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, 
        text='Нажми', reply_markup=markup)
        counter1 = counter1+1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: вы хотите отправить кнопку, а через некоторое время удалить её даже если она не была нажата? и зачем сначала `counter1 = int(call.data)`, а после `str(counter1)`?

Comment: Дело не в этом. А в том, что я не могу запустить процесс проверки по времени. Клавиатура на себя все перехватывает

Comment: Я не увидел ответ на свой вопрос из комментария